# Django : Form Successful but image not uploaded

Tags: python, django, django-file-upload

**MODELS.PY**

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    campaign_image = models.ImageField(default="profilepic.jpg",upload_to="campaign_pictures")
```

**FORMS.PY**

```
class RaiseFundsFrom3(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = ['campaign_image']
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
@login_required
def raise_funds_medical_3(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RaiseFundsFrom3(request.POST, request.FILES or None, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            check = form.save(commit=False)
            check.save()
            return HttpResponse('form worked')
    else:
        form = RaiseFundsFrom3()
        return render(request,'funds/raise_funds_medical_3.html',{'form':form})
```

**URLS.PY**

```
path('raise/medical/photo', views.raise_funds_medical_3, name="raise_funds_medical_3"),
```

**raise_funds_medical_3.html**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group pt-2">
    <small>Photo formats must be PNG / JPG / JPEG</small>
    <input type="file" name="campaign_image" />
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-lg button_bfg_blue" type="submit"> <small><b> NEXT  </b></small> </button>
</form>
```

on form submit, i do not get any error, but image is not uploaded to the required folder.
however, in the raise_funds_medical_3 function within views.py, if i remove instance=request.user, the image gets uploaded but i get following error : *NOT NULL constraint failed: funds_campaign.user_id*

Comment: what's your MEDIA variable value in settings.py?

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'pictures')
MEDIA_URL = '/pictures/'

Comment: You get "form worked" text printed in your browser? Your view does not handle the case that the form is not valid (it returns None in that case).

Comment: Also, `instance=request.user` is **wrong**, the form is a model form for `Campaign` not for `User` so its instance cannot be `request.user`. Assign the user **after** saving the form with commit=False: `check = form.save(commit=False); check.user = request.user; check.save()`.

Comment: @dirkgroten : the image got saved after i used check.user = request.user. Can you explain the flaw in my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form is a `ModelForm` for a `Campaign`, so its `instance` needs to be a `Campaign`. Don't assign `request.user` as its `instance`!

Now, your form isn't including the `user` field which is required to save a `Campaign`, so you should assign that yourself in the view before saving to the database:

```
campaign = form.save(commit=False)  # this gives your the form's instance
campaign.user = request.user  # this assigns the user
campaign.save()  # this commits to the database
```

Also you should handle the case where the form isn't valid. This is quite simple, just **un-indent** the last `return` in your view function, so that `return render(...)` is also called in case the `form` isn't valid.

Finally, instead of returning a response when the form is valid, it's good practice to **redirect** to another view. This way, when the user refreshes the page, the form isn't submitted again. Your final code should look like this:

```
@login_required
def raise_funds_medical_3(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RaiseFundsFrom3(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            check = form.save(commit=False)
            check.user = request.user
            check.save()
            return redirect(<url_pattern>)
    else:
        form = RaiseFundsFrom3()
    return render(request,'funds/raise_funds_medical_3.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: it all makes after reading your answer. Thank you so much.

how can i get the uploaded file name or file url ??

Comment: if you have an instance `campaign` then `campaign.campaign_image.url` is the full url to the image which you can use in the `src` attribute of `<img>`

Answer (score 0):

Supplementary answer to [dirkgroten's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59663775/5246906)

I have come to completely hate the conventional structuring of a Django Function-based View. They can be re-factored by inverting the validity test and adding one line so that one and only one instantiation of a form is present. The result is IMO far easier to read, and easily generalizes for a view displaying two or more forms.

```
def raise_funds_medical_3(request):
    args = [request.POST, request.FILES or None] if request.method == "POST" else []
    form = RaiseFundsFrom3(*args)
    if request.method != "POST" or not form.is_valid():
        # unbound form or form not valid
        return render(request,'funds/raise_funds_medical_3.html',{'form':form})

    # form is valid so do the processing and redirect
    check = form.save(commit=False)
    check.user = request.user
    check.save()
    return redirect(<url_pattern>)
```

If you want to process >1 form, the test becomes

```
    if request.method != "POST" or any(
        [ not form.is_valid(), not form2.is_valid(), ...]):
```

which forces evaluation of `.is_valid()` for all forms, even if the first was not valid, so that *all* the error messages are shown to the user.

In a complex business application, the processing of a successful form submission may be quite a few more lines of code than this simple example. Having it at the end, not indented, isolated from all the boilerplate save the `return redirect(...)`, makes things much easier!